# Why does C++ typedef throw an error when a namespace and an enum within that namespace share a name?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, typedef

When I have an enum defined as such:

```
    namespace ns
    {
        namespace Bar
        {
            static enum Foo {
                VAL1,
                VAL2,
                VAL3
            };
        }
   }
```

I can use:

```
typedef ns::Bar::Foo Foo;
```

to simplify parameter types elsewhere in my code. However, when I change the definition to:

```
namespace ns
{
    namespace Foo
    {
        static enum Foo {
            VAL1,
            VAL2,
            VAL3
        };
    }
}
```

And try to use:

```
typedef ns::Foo::Foo Foo;
```

I get:

```
Error: enum 'ns::Foo::Foo' has no member 'Foo'
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because C-style enums don't create namespaces (as C doesn't have namespaces). Use `enum class Foo`.

Comment: `static enum` is wrong, remove the `static`

Comment: Unable to reproduce with or without `static`. `static` does generate a completely different error, mind you. Neither case should compile so long at that `static` is allowed to live.

Comment: `static enum` is an error.  If you fix this and the problem persists, please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I should clarify that the original error was a Visual Studio Intellisense error, not a compiler error. When I removed `static`, the code generated compiler error `C2365: 'ns::Foo' : redefinition; previous definition was 'namespace'.`. I don't have access to `enum class` in Visual Studio 2010, so it looks like I'm stuck with `enum Foo` within `namespace Bar`.

Comment: @PatrickM sounds like a bug in *Intellisense* then.

Comment: What about `using namespace ns::Foo` instead of typedef? No need for several specific typedef afterwards. And I recommend to put the `using namespace` statement into a cpp file, where you need the type (unless you need it as class member or for function call, then you must put it into the hpp file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum` does not create a namespace of its own, hence Intellisense being unable to differentiate between `ns::Foo` and `ns::Foo::Foo`.

Solution is simply to stick to the top example and remove `static`:

```
namespace ns
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        enum Foo {
            VAL1,
            VAL2,
            VAL3
        };
    }
}
```

(since `enum class` is unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, other than that misplaced `static` in enum definition, there's nothing wrong with

```
typedef ns::Foo::Foo Foo;
```

and it compiles perfectly fine in any conforming C++ compiler. How you managed to end up with *"enum 'ns::Foo::Foo' has no member 'Foo'"* is not clear.

Secondly, while it is true that classic unscoped enums introduce the names of their member constants into the enclosing namespace, starting from C++11 you can still use scoped names to refer "into" such enums, if you so prefer. For example, this is perfectly valid

```
int i = ns::Foo::Foo::VAL1;
```

and equivalent to

```
int i = ns::Foo::VAL1;
```